# Display 2 tables in 1 view

Tags: laravel

I want to display 2 tables in 1 view

like this:

```
{{ $match->title }}
{{ $distance->distance }}
```

but I can't get it to work.

This is my controller:

```
public function bikeGamesMatch(Request $request){ 
    $matches = BikeGame::find($request->id);
    $distances = Distance::find($request->id);
    dd($matches);                          
    return view('bike_games.match', compact("matches","distances"));
}
```

why does the `$distances` return to `null` when I `dd()`: it?

this is my view:

```
<th scope="col" class="text-center"><strong>Game Title:</strong>
             @foreach($matches as $match)
             {{ $match->title }}
             @endforeach
              </th>
                <th scope="col" class="text-center"><strong>Target: Distance</strong>
              @foreach($distances as $distance) 
             {{ $distance->distance }} {{ $distance->unit }}
             @endforeach
</th>
```

If I do this the view gives me 404

```
$matches = BikeGame::find($request->id)->firstOrFail();
$distances = Distance::find($request->id)->firstOrFail();
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure the record with the id you're sending exists in table Distance?

Comment: It's not an answer. 
But with the view it seems that bike_game have a relative distance. Then you should use Laravel Relationships. 
The variable name is plural and you are getting a single object in it.
one query param you are searching to find two objects in their primary key. 
Really its complicated to imagine what you are doing. Your colleagues will not be happy with you.

Comment: Don't use loop in view. You are get single object from Find or First or firstOrFail functions.

Comment: I wont foreach in view?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
$matches = BikeGame::find($request->id);
$distances = Distance::find($request->id);
```

to

```
$matches = BikeGame::find($request->get('id'));
$distances = Distance::find($request->get('id');
```

Comment: "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\bike_sprint\resources\views\bike_games\match.blade.php)" I got this error

Comment: when I commented the line that cause the error ( <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('bikegames.leave', ['id'=>$matches->id]) }}" role="button">Leave Room</a> ) 

I got this error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\bike_sprint\resources\views\bike_games\match.blade.php)"

even if my foreach looks like this

```
 @foreach($matches as $match)
             {{ $match->title }}
 @endforeach
```

and this 

```
  @foreach($distances as $distance) 
             {{ $distance->distance }} {{ $distance->unit }}
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this changes

```
$matches = BikeGame::where('id',$request->id)->first();
$distances = Distance::where('id',$request->id)->first();
```

Hope it useful for you.

Comment: bike_game_id
distance_id

where is this? there is no table like this in my database, only "id" on both tables

Comment: @Hacki check my updated answer. I wrote for as example.

Answer (score 0):

In view before using `foreach` try to check

```
isset($matches) && count(matches) >0
```

if this condition is true then use `foreach`.

Comment: Use of undefined constant matches - assumed 'matches' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\bike_sprint\resources\views\bike_games\match.blade.php) 

I got this error, after changing changing 'matches' and 'distances' i got this error count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\bike_sprint\resources\views\bike_games\match.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

use has one relationship between two model :: BikeGame & Distance .

give then Unique id. like Bike_id & Distance_id.

Bikegame model =>

```
public function distance(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Distance','Distance_id', 'id');
}
```

Distance Model =>

```
public function bike()
{
    return $this->belongsTO('App\Bikegame', 'Distance_id','id');
}
```

in your controller ex.

```
 $bike = BikeGame::with('distance')->find($id);
 $bike->bikename    = request('bikename');
 $bike->distance->distacekm = $request->distacekm;
 $bike->distance->dismm = $request->dismm;
```

try this step